# Confidence interval for sum(observed) (continuous, right-skewed) divided by sum(expected) (continuous, right-skewed)

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval

I need confidence intervals for an o/e metric based on a continuous variable (observed days/ expected days) sumed up for all the people in the population.

Comment: What have you tried? What distributions are you assuming? Have you considered bootstrapping?

Comment: fishers and midpoint used by standardized mortality ratio, but that isn't correct. I've considered bootstrapping. The observed and expected will both be right-skewed.